# pgfplots Line Histogram

Tags: pgfplots, statistics, histogram

I have a histogram. It is created from data in a CSV file.

I would like to connect the mid points on each bar with a smooth line.

My intention is to plot multiple series and show just the lines.

It is important that the bins remain centered under the mid-points.

[image: I would like a line, please.]

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
A
2
3
4
2
3
4
5
6
9
9
1
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
1000 sep={},
title={Title},
xlabel={X Label},
ylabel={Y Label},
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.05,0.5)},anchor=south},
xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
ytick distance=2,
width=\textwidth, %10.5cm
height=6cm,
ymin=0
]

%%%
\addplot +[
black,
fill=lightgray,
hist={bins=5,
data min=0,
data max=10,
}
] table[y=A, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with

```
\addplot +[
hist={bins=5,
  data min=0,
  data max=10,
  handler/.style={sharp plot},
  intervals=false
},
x filter/.expression={x+1} % shift curve to center point
] table[y=A, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
```

The `handler` style for `hist`, described in the manual at the end of the section on histograms, is for just this sort of thing. `intervals=false` is to avoid getting an extra data point at the end (see examples in manual), and finally the `x filter` is to shift the curve to the mid points of the bars.

Complete code, with the normal histogram included as well is below. Note I added `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}`. That setting will, at least, improve the default positioning of the axis labels, so your custom positioning might not be needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
A
2
3
4
2
3
4
5
6
9
9
1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \centering
\begin{axis}[
/pgf/number format/.cd,
use comma,
1000 sep={},
title={Title},
xlabel={X Label},
ylabel={Y Label},
xticklabel style={rotate=90, anchor=near xticklabel},
ytick distance=2,
width=\textwidth, %10.5cm
height=6cm,
ymin=0
]

\addplot [
ybar interval,
fill=blue!10,
hist={bins=5,
  data min=0,
  data max=10,
}
] table[y=A, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

%%%
\addplot +[
hist={bins=5,
  data min=0,
  data max=10,
  handler/.style={sharp plot},
  intervals=false
},
x filter/.expression={x+1} % shift curve to center point
] table[y=A, col sep=comma] {data.csv};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `handler/.style={sharp plot,smooth}` if you really want to make it smooth.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I added a slight amendment to your answer (mainly because I know I'll have to revisit this question in the future to remind myself!) in case a user has `ybar` contained in `\begin{axis}` instead of `ybar interval` in `\addplot`: simply adding `fill=none,` above `hist={bins=5,}` in `\addplot`. Then you get the line without the area under it being filled.